# Is there a way to check if there is a pending migrate before running the actual migration with the flyway cli?

Tags: flyway

I want to be able to run a command and determine if there is a pending migration. This is going to be scripted so the best thing would be a command that returns easy to parse output.

The only command I could find for this is [info](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/v6/commandline/info) but the output stinks. I want to confirm if there is a way to get parsable output.

For example this command:

```
flyway -locations="filesystem:schema_migration_files" \
    -user="userxyz" \
    -password="lsdkfklsdfjld" \
    -url=jdbc:postgresql://myserver:5432/mydb \
    info
```

Gives me this atrocious output:
[image]

I can parse that mess myself. I would probably just check if string "Pending" is in the output, but I'm not sure how reliable that would be. I just need to determine if there is or isn't a pending migration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`-outputType=json`](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/usage/commandline/info#sample-json-output) command line argument, and then parse the output.

Comment: The doc I linked to appears to be version 6 and it looks like version 7 added this switch